# How to get the local time in the form of a Date object

Tags: javascript

If I have a Date object:

```
var event = new Date();
```

I want a Date object for the Uk.

I've seen `var localDate = event.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'Europe/London' });`

But this turns it in to a String.

But I want to keep it a `Date` object?

Comment: it does not make sense the dates are **always** UTC, it is only on the display that you can choose the region

Comment: so `var event = new Date();` will always return the UTC in node for example?

Comment: Date objects *internally* use UTC, but that shouldn't matter to you. You can format it before displaying, as mentioned by @MisterJojo

Comment: yes, anywhere, if at the same time on a computers  in China and Peru, the `new Date ()` will have the same value.

Comment: @MisterJojo  Internally and if both computers have the correct time, then yes.  basically  `Date.getTime()` in the UK will give the same value as `Date.getTime()` in China if both were executed at the same time..  IOW: Dates in Javascript are a universal time constant, that's the U part in `UTC`, rather than BST & GMT etc.

Comment: @Keith, Of course, my answer is global, if we want to go into details we should also talk about NTP servers, the time zone setting is secondary

Comment: @MisterJojo  Sorry, I meant my reply to the OP.. about always UTC , in node etc..

Comment: @Keith It's okay, the notions of time have always fascinated me: many people still believe that the earth turns on itself in 24 hours, and do not understand why we switched to UTC time while keeping the GMT system for time zones ...